# Howto create a detailed report of all actions by publishing with sqlpackage.exe?

Tags: sql-server, ssdt, deployment

When publishing ssdt projects from visual studio I realized that a "deploymentreport.txt" file is created on hard disk.

[sqlpackage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx) can be executed with the action "DeployReport" that creates a report of all actions that would have been done during a publishing.

Is there any way to create this report DURING the publishing? As a result / log?

I don't want to create the report first and call sqlpackage.exe with the publish action again afterwards to get a report and do the deployment. This might be much more work to do than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`/DeployReportPath:deploymentreport.txt"`
ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish#parameters-for-the-publish-action